# redirectng mobile friendly site to desktop client

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile, mobile

I created two distinctly different sites. One for desktop viewing, one in smaller, mobile. All in notepad. I redirected the desktop to mobile with a script as follows;

```
  if (screen.width <= 760) {
    window.location = "http://m.website.ca/page.htm";
  }
```

This ensured that the desktop version displayed in ipad rather than a mobile version. I tried using the same script, with a max width of as low as 500 in the mobile pages to redirect to the desktop version, and created a loop, whereby neither page displays, but rather, keeps refreshing ie; desktop to mobile, mobile to desktop.

Now, the problem i have is, if you type the m.website.ca addresses in the desktop, they show up. I don't want people to see the mobile addresses.
For this to run seamlessly, someone receiving a link on social media with the m. addresses, i am trying to get them to load in desktop if a desktop client is in use.

Answer (score 2):

You have to ensure that you're on the wrong site by checking the location's hostname before redirecting:

```
if (location.hostname !== 'm.website.ca' && screen.width <= 760) {
  window.location = "http://m.website.ca/page.htm";
}
```

Otherwise, you will get an infinite loop as you stated.

Comment: does this require entering the browser names? Ie; explorer, firefox, chrome? and where would i put them if so?

Comment: I tried it and it'll need tweaking, but i think your solution just may work. I entered in your coding, with mine on the mobile, and it wont resolve to the page, but to the domain,BUT it does work to block the mobile version in desktop. Thank you for your help.

Comment: That should work on every browser. Of course you should write the code to redirect to the desktop site too.

Comment: The solution is to use this on desktop; <link rel="alternate" media="only screen and (max-width: 640px)" href="m.example.net/page.htm" /> and <link rel="canonical" href="http://example.net/page.htm"/> on the corresponding mobile page. Then, If someone copies the mobile, when they click on the link, it will change automatically to the desktop. AT least, this is how I am assuming it works, as I put all the fb tags with app id etc. Thanks everyone for your help!